# Timezone GMT to GMT+5:30 or IST

Tags: php, time, timezone, timezone-offset

I tried

SetEnv TZ Asia/Kolkata in htaccess and

in php.ini

php_value date.timezone "Asia/Kolkata"

it is not working. the data entry on database showing local time.

I have cloud server GMT timing and I need to change it to GMT+5:30 or IST

Kindly help

Comment: Have a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Comment: MySQL's timezone isn't necessarily the same as PHP's. You have to change both, although it's often a better decision to use UTC everywhere and convert *on display* to a particular timezone.